# Why does my function receive boolean state update after the second onclick handler execution?

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, material-ui, react-tsx

I have a React functional component `function ListElement` and a corresponding `interface ListElementProps` through which I pass a few properties to the component. This component has a MUI `ListItem` with some text and clickable icons as children.

Two of these icons form a functionality similar to an actual checkbox, but this component can't be used here. Together these two icons have an onClickHandler function called `handleInclude`. These two are supposed to toggle between including the item in the update or excluding it from the update.

The `ListItem` also contains a nested list with some extra information on the updated values in the file itself, but this itself is unrelated to the problem at hand.

The code that makes up my component is as follows.

```
interface ListElementProps {
  parentContainer: BlobContainerData; //custom type that contains multiple blobData, needed for the update
  blobData: BlobData; //custom type that contains the file to be included/excluded in the update
  onUpdate: (update: BlobContainerData) => void; //parent's update function
}

export function ListElement(props: ListElementProps) {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
  const [blobData, setBlobData] = React.useState<BlobData>(props.blobData);
  const [parent, setParent] = React.useState<BlobContainerData>(props.parentContainer);
  const [data, setData] = React.useState<Array<any>>([]);
  const [included, setIncluded] = React.useState<boolean>(props.blobData.toLive);
  const [mounting, setMounting] = React.useState<boolean>(true);

//mounter
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      let loadedData: Array<any> = await extractBlobData(props.blobData.value);
      setData(loadedData);
    };

    fetchData().catch(console.error);
    setMounting(false);
    console.log('finished confirmationdialog mount')
    console.log(included, open)
  }, []);

   //#region handlers
   const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(opened => !opened);
  };

  const handleIncluded = () => {
    setIncluded(including => !including);
    onUpdate()
  }

  //#endregion

  //Update the parent's blobdata
  const onUpdate = () => {
    let updatedBlobData: BlobData = {...blobData, edited: true, toLive: included}

    console.log(updatedBlobData);
    setBlobData(updatedBlobData);
    
    let updatedContainerData: BlobContainerData = {...parent,
      blobsData: props.parentContainer.blobsData.map((blob) => { 
        if (blob.key === updatedBlobData.key) {
          return updatedBlobData;
        } else { 
          return blob; 
        }
      }),
    }

    console.log(updatedContainerData)
    setParent(updatedContainerData)

    //props.onUpdate(newContainerData);
  }

  //build list children
  let listChildElements = data.filter(function (element) {
    return element.status !== "live" && element.status !== undefined
  }).map((member) => {
    return <ListChild member={member} onUpdate={onUpdate} />
  })

  //return the component
  if (listChildElements.length > 0) {
    return (
      <>
        <ListItem key={props.blobData.key}>
          <ListItemText>{props.blobData.key}</ListItemText>
          {
            included ? 
            <CheckBoxIcon onClick={handleIncluded} /> :
            <CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon onClick={handleIncluded} />
          }
          {
            open ? 
            <ExpandLessIcon onClick={handleOpen} /> :
            <ExpandMoreIcon onClick={handleOpen} />
          }
        </ListItem>
        <Collapse in={open}>
          <List component="div">
            {listChildElements}
          </List>
        </Collapse>
      </>
    );
  }
  else {
    return null;
  }
}

/**
 * Build a child member for the list of changes in the confirmation window
 * @param member item of the data set in the container
 * @param onUpdate update function
 * @returns a child for the list of changes in the container
 */
const ListChild = (member: any) => {
  return (
    <ListItem
      key={member.key}
    >
      <ListItemText>{member.key} {member.status}</ListItemText>
    </ListItem>
  );
}
```

I have also tried to use an `useEffect` hook with `included` in the dependency array, however this did not solve the problem. This explains the presence of the `const [mounting, setMounting]` line, to prevent this effect from executing without any data and thus crashing the application.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  if(!mounting) {
    onUpdate()
  }
}, [included])
```

Before I click the `CheckboxIcon`, included is already true due to it receiving it's value from the parent in the `React.useState`. When I click the icon for the first time, it runs through the update but doesn't do anything with it, the Icon now swaps to the `CheckboxBlankOutlinedIcon`. When I click it again, The update function now executes properly, the icon swaps back to `CheckboxIcon` and it makes an `updatedBlobData` where `toLive: false`. This is naturally not correct.

This leads me to believe that what actually happens truthwise is something like `true true false` inside the function.

The expected behavior however is `true false true` as does happen between swapping the icons.

I'm still a bit inexperienced so I might be doing some things ineffectively, I'm well aware. But for now, how do I fix this?

**UPDATE:**
It baffles me, but adding back this `useEffect` fixed my problem, when it didn't actually work before.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!mounting) {
      onUpdate()
    }
  }, [included])
```